# Alternative definition of Reynolds number?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, definition

I came across something interesting which I cannot find much reference to elsewhere, where a force called "critical force" is defined as $\eta^2/\rho$. This is obtained by dimensional analysis and is attributed the property of being the critical force for laminar flow.

Now if you see carefully, defining Reynold's number as $(6\pi\eta rv)/(\eta^2/\rho)$ sans the $6\pi$, we get the same formula as Reynold's number. This seems intuitively incorrect to me that when larger viscous force is present, the flow will be turbulent. What am I doing wrong? Or is the definition for critical force totally wrong?

I found someone who has found critical force (again, by dimensional analysis) [here](http://www.sfu.ca/~eemberly/phys347/lectures/9_Fluids_Low_Reynolds.pdf).

Comment: I agree, i am having difficulty intuitively understanding this critical force. I understand that one can define such a quantity from dimensional analysis but the physical meaning of it is lost on me. Unlike the Reynolds number which is simply the ratio of inertial to viscous forces. One advantage i can see however is that the critical force is only dependent on material properties not on any system properties like a length or velocity scale. That allows to compare different materials on their likelihood to be laminar or turbulent i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to interpret it properly. It really boils down to the third law and how you are looking at things.

When you see that more viscous force is being experienced by the body, it actually means that you are applying more force to the body externally too. In this sense, as the external force increases, you have a greater probability of getting a turbulent flow.

Another way to look at it is that when the flow is turbulent, you *are* actually going to have a huge viscous force, keeping everything constant. Viscous force would increase trying to keep the flow laminar, but at some point it would fail to, but the force itself would keep increasing. Thus, higher viscous forces mean higher turbulence.